# Dynamic Serving with different url

Tags: seo, mobile, responsive-webdesign

We have a website math.tutorvista.com.

We use dynamic serving web pages.

Desktop URL:

https://math.tutorvista.com/geometry/analytical-geometry.html

Mobile URL:

https://math.tutorvista.com/geometry/analytical-geometry.html?view=simple

I have a couple of questions on this:

1) Is it a Bad SEO to use Dynamic serving than Responsive web pages?
2) Should we use  **"?view=simple"** on to the URL to differentiate?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use for mobile SEO different options as long as the web implementation is correct:

- Responsive design
- Dynamic serving
- Separate URLs

In the case of dynamic serving, you should use the same URL for desktop and mobile (delete the parameter). Just check [the correct dynamic implementation](https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/dynamic-serving?hl=en) and avoid the [common mistakes](https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/common-mistakes).